# Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException Connection refused selenium codeception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to make testing in **Yii2** with **codeception**. For acceptence test i installed selenium.

Selenium is running perfectly with this command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.
```

But when running test with `codecept run` i got this error

> ```
> > [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException]     Connection
> > refused  selenium codeception
> ```

Comment: Is Selenium running on correct port? Default port used by WebDriver module is 4444. http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#Configuration

Comment: Yes its running .